# Return statement executing before firebase response

Tags: android

I am using FirebaseFirestore to nosql database, I have a dedicated java class to execute all the firebase Read, Write and Delete queries.

The problem I am facing is while fetching my Users data from Firestore, and storing it in an array list. After all the users are update in the arraylist, then i am returning that list to update the UI. but my funciton below is returning the empty list and then the firebase query is updating the data into the list.

```
public List<Users> getAllUsers() {
    return loadAllUserData();
}
private List<Users> loadAllUserData() {
    List<Users> usersList  = new ArrayList<>();

    mFirebaseFirestore.collection(USER_DATA).get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(queryDocumentSnapshots -> {
                List<DocumentSnapshot> docSnap = 
                queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();
                
                for (DocumentSnapshot docs : docSnap) {
                    Users user = docs.toObject(Users.class);
                    usersList.add(user);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: loaded Users : " + usersList.size());
                }
            });
    Log.d(TAG, "loadAllUserData: Returning users : " + usersList.size());

    return usersList;
}
```

logs

2022-09-01 23:13:38.786 /com.app D/Repository: Repository: Called

2022-09-01 23:13:38.787 /com.app D/Repository: Repository: Called

2022-09-01 23:13:38.787 /com.app D/Repository: loadAllUserData: Returning users : 0

2022-09-01 23:13:38.962 /com.app D/Repository: onSuccess: loaded Users : 1

2022-09-01 23:13:38.962 /com.app D/Repository: onSuccess: loaded Users : 2

2022-09-01 23:13:38.962 /com.app D/Repository: onSuccess: loaded Users : 3

2022-09-01 23:13:38.963 /com.app D/Repository: onSuccess: loaded Users : 4

Answer (score 0):

The get() operation is an asynchronous operation. Because of that, the return will be executed before the addOnSuccessListener.

Comment: I tried using synchronized for the get method and it still dosent work. Could you please guide me as to how do i resolve this issue ?